# Opening a popup from code throws exception

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, popup

I am working on an app within Xamarin Android on VS Community 2017. I want to launch a `Popup` from `FAB - FloatingActionButton`. I created the popup xml layout separately and when I launch the popup the debugger throws an exception but there is no error code displayed so I dont know what is causing the issue.

My best guess is something is wrong with the xml layout file for the popup. I have checked it numerous times but everything seems okay to me. The `RelativePanel` in android works awfully different than in UWP and maybe I am doing something wrong there.

Anyway, here is the code...
Popup layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="5dp">
<TextView
    android:text="Sort By:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/moviesSortByText"
    android:minHeight="28dp"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical" />
<Spinner
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/moviesSortSpinner"
    android:minWidth="120dp"
    android:minHeight="28dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/moviesSortByText" />
<TextView
    android:text="Genre:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/moviesGenresText"
    android:layout_below="@id/moviesSortByText"
    android:minHeight="28dp"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical" />
<Spinner
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/moviesSortByText"
    android:id="@+id/moviesGenresSpinner"
    android:minWidth="120dp"
    android:minHeight="28dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/moviesGenresText" />
<TextView
    android:text="Country:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/moviesCountryText"
    android:layout_below="@id/moviesGenresText"
    android:minHeight="28dp"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical" />
<Spinner
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/moviesGenresText"
    android:id="@+id/moviesCountrySpinner"
    android:minWidth="120dp"
    android:minHeight="28dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/moviesCountryText" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The code behind in the activity:

```
moviesOptionsBtn = FindViewById<FloatingActionButton>(Resource.Id.moviesOptionsFAB);
moviesOptionsBtn.Click += MoviesOptionsBtn_Click;

    private void MoviesOptionsBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // create a flyout with 3 spinners for sorting, genres and countries
        var popupView = LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.moviesOptionsPopupLayout, null);
        var popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent, true)
        {
            Touchable = true,
            Focusable = true,
            OutsideTouchable = true
        };
        // find spinners and fill them with values
        sortSpinner = popupView.FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.moviesSortSpinner);
        genreSpinner = popupView.FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.moviesGenresSpinner);
        countrySpinner = popupView.FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.moviesCountrySpinner);
        sortSpinner.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem, ViewHelper.SortList);
        genreSpinner.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem, ViewHelper.GenresList);
        countrySpinner.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem, ViewHelper.CountryList);
        // register selections
        sortSpinner.ItemSelected += MoviesOptionsSpinner_ItemSelected;
        genreSpinner.ItemSelected += MoviesOptionsSpinner_ItemSelected;
        countrySpinner.ItemSelected += MoviesOptionsSpinner_ItemSelected;

        popupWindow.ShowAsDropDown(moviesOptionsBtn);
    }
```

The `FAB` is displayed okay and the exception is only thrown after the last line. All the other code appears to be working fine.

Can someone look at my code and tell me if there is something that i am doing wrong?

Comment: First of all: Have you cleaned the project? Restarted your IDE? Removed every child in the relative layout and test one by one, maybe theres an issue with a child. Also i can't believe no error will be put out. Check the android logs. Are you developing with VS? If so, when it hits the exception, you might have the option to hit the "Continue" button again. doing so can lead to the debugger putting out the exception. Good luck!

Comment: Check this `new ArrayAdapter(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem, ViewHelper.SortList)` method, refer to this link:https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context, int, int, T[]), the third parameter is wrong, or could you please show your layout?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/samples/Notifications/Application/res/layout/simple_spinner_item.html, this is the `SimpleSpinnerItem` layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments, I found out the source of my problem.

In Android, the `Spinner`'s adapter property is rather different. As what I did, one of the 2nd and 3rd parameters in

```
sortSpinner.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem, ViewHelper.SortList);
```

is a resource for `TextView` but I was passing it a style from Android framework and that was causing the exception. To make it right, I had to use only one style for the closed `Spinner` and after that set the 2nd resource for the opened list.

```
var spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem, ViewHelper.SortList);
spinnerAdapter.SetDropdownResource(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem);
sortSpinner.Adapter = spinnerAdapter;
```

That solved the problem so I thought I should put it here for future reference. Thanks for the effort though.